# How to open a file as you type out its directory?

Tags: command-line

I am new to using the terminal in Ubuntu and I was wondering how I could open the file "armored.jpg" as I type out the whole path.

For instance, if I type `cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/` and then type `xdg-open armored.jpg` in the current directory it opens the picture.

However when I type:

```
cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/ xdg-open armored.jpg
```

or

```
cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/armored.jpg
```

or

```
cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/armored
```

it does not work.

Can anyone explain why this is?  I want to know if I can open the file with something like this:

```
cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/**command goes here**/armored.jpg
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

`xdg-open ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/armored.jpg`

`cd` means change directory so essentially terminal is expecting a path-to-directory where you want to change to.

`xdg-open` opens a file in default applications but as it opens a file it expects path-to-file, you can also use `xdg-open` to open directory in nautilus(if it is your default file manager) in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You should be running the command and passing the path to the file as an argument.  Your commands would work if you rearranged it like so:

```
xdg-open ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/armored.jpg
```

The first word you use in the terminal is the command you are trying to run (which can be a program, built-in, function, etc) and all the other words are passed to that program as arguments.  In this case, you're telling `xdg-open` to display your JPG, so you'll put the command first, and then the path to the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double ampersands. Like:

`cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/ && xdg-open armored.jpg`

This will execute the first command, and move to the second if the first is successful.

or you could do:

`cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/; xdg-open armored.jpg`

Which will run the first command, and then the second, whether the first fails or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/ xdg-open armored.jpg
```

If you run this command, terminal considers the whole after `cd` as a directory and it breaks if it contains any spaces and discards the part after space.In this case, the above command will get you only into the directory `~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x`. If you really want to open the file using xdg-open then your command needs breaking like below.

```
cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/; xdg-open armored.jpg
```

The terminal parses the second command(ie, after ;) whether the first command succeeded or not.

Example:

```
$ cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/; xdg-open armored.jpg
bash: cd: /home/avinash/Pictures/Wallpapers/test x/: No such file or directory
gvfs-open: armored.jpg: error opening location: Error when getting information for file '/home/avinash/armored.jpg': No such file or directory
```

or

```
cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/ && xdg-open armored.jpg
```

The terminal parses the second command only if the first command would ended in success.

Example:

```
$ cd ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/test\ x/ && xdg-open armored.jpg
bash: cd: /home/avinash/Pictures/Wallpapers/test x/: No such file or directory
```